# Nest Json data from MySql queries in C#

Tags: c#, json, api, nested

Im trying to make a nested json with data get from a MySQL DB

For the moment i got

```
 //Obtener el root de info
        public List<Root> GetRoot()
        {
            using (var conexion = ObtenerConexion())
            {
                conexion.Open();
                var query = @"SELECT id AS Id, fullname AS NombreCurso,  MID(fullname, INSTR(fullname, ""RLAB""), 20) AS codigoOferta
                                FROM mo_course 
                                WHERE  MID(fullname, INSTR(fullname, ""RLAB""), 20) != '';";
                var resultado = conexion.Query<Root>(query);
                
                foreach (var item in resultado)
                {
                    Root root = new Root();
                    root.codigoOferta = item.codigoOferta;
                    root.listaAlumnos = new List<ListaAlumno>();
                    roots.Add(root);
                    conexion.Close();
                }
                return roots;
            }
        }

        public List<ListaAlumno> GetAlumnos(string codigoOferta)
        {
            using (var conexion = ObtenerConexion())
            {
                conexion.Open();
                var query = @"SELECT mo_role_assignments.userid AS Id, firstname AS Nombre, lastname AS Apellido, LEFT(mo_user.idnumber, LENGTH(mo_user.idnumber - 2)) AS rutAlumno,
                                RIGHT(mo_user.idnumber, 1) AS dvAlumno, email AS Correo, mo_course.fullname AS NombreCurso, mo_course.idnumber AS codigoOferta,
                                FROM_UNIXTIME(startdate) AS fechaInicio, FROM_UNIXTIME(enddate) AS fechaFin
                                FROM mo_course
                                INNER JOIN mo_context ON mo_context.instanceid = mo_course.id
                                INNER JOIN mo_role_assignments ON mo_context.id = mo_role_assignments.contextid
                                INNER JOIN mo_user ON (mo_role_assignments.userid = mo_user.id)";

                var resultado = conexion.Query<ListaAlumno>(query);
                foreach (var item in resultado)
                {
                    ListaAlumno alumno = new ListaAlumno();
                    alumno.codigoOferta = item.codigoOferta;
                    alumno.rutAlumno = item.rutAlumno;
                    alumno.dvAlumno = item.dvAlumno;
                    alumno.tiempoConectividad = 0;
                    alumno.estado = 0;
                    alumno.porcentajeAvance = 0;
                    alumno.fechaInicio = item.fechaInicio;
                    alumno.fechaFin = item.fechaFin;
                    alumno.fechaEjecucion = "";
                    alumno.listaModulos = new List<ListaModulo>();
                    listaAlumnos.Add(alumno);
                }
                conexion.Close();
            }
            return listaAlumnos;
        }

    }
```

but i cant find a way to do the variable to nest the data, since i getting the data as direct query the parameter "codigoOferta" in GetAlumnos is not working

The idea its to do the following

```
{
    "rutOtec": "9999999-9",
    "idSistema": 1350,
    "token": "AAAAAA-ASSS-DDDDd-8FFF-2FFFFFFFFD2",
    "codigoOferta": "RSJ-D444-555-666666",
    "codigoGrupo": "RSJ-D444-555-666666",
    "codigoEnvio": "RSJ-D444-555-666666",
    "listaAlumnos": [
        {
            "rutAlumno": 255544466,
            "dvAlumno": "4",
            "tiempoConectividad": 199112,
            "estado": 1,
            "porcentajeAvance": 99,
            "fechaInicio": "2022-07-28",
            "fechaFin": "2022-10-24",
            "fechaEjecucion": "2022-10-24",
            "listaModulos": [
                {
                    "codigoModulo": "ARS027773588877",
                    "tiempoConectividad": 7964,
                    "estado": 1,
                    "porcentajeAvance": 100,
                    "fechaInicio": "2022-07-28",
                    "fechaFin": "2022-10-24",
                    "listaActividades": [
                        {
                            "codigoActividad": "Excel"
                        },
                        {
                            "codigoActividad": "Video interactivo de introducci\u00f3n a Excel"
                        },
```

but since for each student in listaAlumno the data change i need to nest the variables